# Error to start pre-built spark-master when slf4j is not installed

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using ubuntu to setup standalone spark. But it failed to find the slf4j package while I'm using the pre-built spark.

```
./spark-1.4.1-bin-without-hadoop/sbin/start-master.sh

Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle//bin/java -cp /root/spark-1.4.1-bin-without-hadoop/sbin/../conf/:/root/spark-1.4.1-bin-without-hadoop/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.2.0.jar -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip localhost --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
```

I'm sorry that I should not use spark-1.4.1-bin-without-hadoop and it works when I download spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6. So that could be the problem of my usage, not Spark.

Answer (score 33):

An easy fix could be use the classpath from the hadoop classpath command, as suggested in the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html):

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
```